# How to launch an app using dialor [android]

Tags: android

I want to launch my android app using my default dialor by using number like #*12121*# and I also want it to hide from user.
How can I achieve this.
I'm a beginner so please explain.

Comment: I'll also give you a free warning-  I worked for a company called SnapInSoftware, which is now owned by Nuance Communications.  We owned the patent on doing this.  I have no idea if Nuance is aggressive about filing suits on it as I no longer work there.

Comment: I'm not using this for commercial purpose. 
When I'm dialing the code in dialor it showing "Connection Problem or Invalid MMI Code." @Gabe Sechan

Comment: Doesn't matter for patents.  Not that I care, that's their problem.  As for why it isn't working-  it isn't a real phone number.  The dialer may be treating it as a USSD code and not actually dialing the call.  In which case its not possible to intercept.